# XFS inodes not neessarily unique?

Tags: linux, debian, xfs, inode

(Debian 10.5, kernel 4.19.132-1 )

My understanding is that inodes are unique on a given filesystem, and indeed if we look at `man inode` we get the following assertion:

> Each  file  in  a filesystem has a unique inode number.

But I do not appear to be seeing this in practice.

I have a `/tmp` filesystem defined as follows in `fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/foo-lv_tmp /tmp            xfs     nodev           0       0
```

But if I experiment with `mktemp` I get the same inode:

```
$ mktemp
/tmp/tmp.BovySvY5Fw
$ echo 'foo'> /tmp/tmp.BovySvY5Fw
$ ls -i /tmp/tmp.BovySvY5Fw
135 /tmp/tmp.BovySvY5Fw
$ rm /tmp/tmp.BovySvY5Fw
$ mktemp
/tmp/tmp.UzUQZROBoo
$ echo 'foo'> /tmp/tmp.UzUQZROBoo
$ ls -i /tmp/tmp.UzUQZROBoo
135 /tmp/tmp.UzUQZROBoo
$ rm /tmp/tmp.UzUQZROBoo
```

I also see the same behaviour outside of `/tmp` e.g. my home dir:

```
foo@bar:~$ echo 'a' > foo
foo@bar:~$ ls -i foo
67135721 foo
foo@bar:~$ rm foo 
foo@bar:~$ echo 'a' > foo
foo@bar:~$ ls -i foo
67135721 foo
foo@bar:~$ rm foo
```

Comment: Your examples don't contradict anything. Once you `rm` a file, it is no longer in the filesystem. So that inode number can be used when you create a new file.

Comment: @Mat Thanks. So in terms of a scenario where I am writing a script to incrementally process files,  relying on the inode might not be such a good idea ?  I have already identified that truncating a file doesn't change an inode (obviously !), but if there are additional scenarios where removing a file could result in a new file with same inode then perhaps I need to think again.

Comment: It's unclear why you would want to use the inode anyway. Once you open a file it's not going anywhere.